Why VGG fine tuning process keeps crashing in colab?
0
I am trying to fine-tune a VGG16 model for an ECG-image classification task with the resolution of 1700 * 2200

I haven't reshaped and reduced the size of the images because I thought some information about the signals might get lost. I developed a basic VGG model to fine-tunning architecture. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to train the model in Google Colab—it consistently crashes due to excessive RAM usage before the training even starts. I'm loading the image details and corresponding classes from a CSV file (formatted as [path|class]) and feeding them into the model pipeline using two specific functions.
def preprocess_image(image_path, label):
  """Loads an image, resizes, and applies preprocessing."""
  img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values
  return img, label

def load_data_from_csv(csv_file, batch_size):
  df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
  image_paths = df['img_path'].tolist()
  labels = df['classification_labels'].tolist()

  # Convert string labels to lists
  labels = [eval(label) for label in labels]

  # One-hot encode labels using the previously fitted MultiLabelBinarizer
  one_hot_encoded_labels = model.encoder.transform(labels)

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, one_hot_encoded_labels))
  dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  return dataset

dataset = load_data_from_csv('data.csv', BATCH_SIZE)

So is the crash associated with my code? If so can you suggest a way to work around this issue(I'm using the free colab plan)

I think this question is about a programming issue and programming issues are generally off-topic here. Having said that, first you need to understand how much memory or RAM the CPUs or GPUs in colab have. Then you need to understand which operations in your codebase are loading data from the file system into the memory and calculate the amount of memory that would be needed. For example, maybe you know that an integer requires 32bits (or whatever) to be stored, then if you have a matrix of 3x3 integers, how many bits do you need? Stuff like that.
